# How to make Opencv 2.4.8 with Python 2.7.5 to work on Windows7 Cygwin64?

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7, cygwin

I spent some 15 hours by now trying to get Opencv 2.4.8 to work with Python 2.7.5 on my Windows7 Cygwin-64 environment.

After some [struggle](http://goo.gl/cUauJd), I've finally managed to get Opencv work with C++, but I'm still not able to call Opencv from Python.

This is what I get when trying to import the cv2 module:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct  2 2013, 22:34:09)
[GCC 4.8.1] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
>>>
```

During the installation (with cmake-gui) of Opencv, all the configuration entries regarding Python were correctly defined.

I've added the path to opencv/bin to my PATH.

I've copied the file cv2.pyd from the opencv distribution to my Python installation's site-packages folder, to no avail.

I've tried to set PYTHONPATH to point to the site-packages directory, but it doesn't help.

To me, it seems like Python is unaware of the cv2 module.

Any pointers on what to try next would be very much appreciated. Also, if someone could provide some insights on how Python in general locates external non-Python modules, over and above placing the corresponding .pyd-file in the site-packages library, would be helpful for further trouble shooting.

TIA.

Comment: try the installer for 64 bit python found [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Comment: You cannot use `cv2.pyd` (or anything else built for Windows Python) with Cygwin's Python; they are incompatible.  Building OpenCV for Cygwin requires [several patches](https://sourceforge.net/p/cygwin-ports/opencv/ci/master/tree/), but binary packages are available from [Ports](http://cygwinports.org/).

Comment: @Yaakov, thx for the conclusive answer. Seems like there's some additional work to do before I'd be able to run OpenCV/Python on my setup. The OpenCV I managed to build from sources works fine with Cygwin's gcc/C++, so I think I stick with C++ for now, most examples seem to be written in C++ anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! I'm now able to run Python with OpenCV.

@Yaakov set me on the right track: once I realized that the cv2.pyd is basically just a dll, the rest came easily: since I had built OpenCV from sources, I started to suspect that there just might be a cv2.dll having been built in that process. Indeed there was, in the lib directory of the OpenCV build-area.

After having copied that file to my python's site-packages directory, everything started working ok.

Additional details [here](http://goo.gl/33v4tU).